# Display decimal point with NSString stringWithFormat in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm a complete novice to objective C/iPad development, but I am trying to build a simple four function calculator on the iPad.

My current biggest difficulty is simply displaying a `.` when the decimal button is pressed. Here is what happens when a button (like two) is pressed.

```
-(IBAction)inTwo:(id)sender {
    display = display*10+2;
    [resultfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",display]];    
}
```

Trying to just do

```
display = display*10+.
```

Is obviously not working. Any way to append a period to the end of display?

Thanks

Comment: To format numbers for output, you should generally use an `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: Just slap it in the `resultfield`, then run it through my handy-dandy DDMathParser: http://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display it you can do this:

```
[resultField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%@", display, @"."]];
```

Then, in your other methods, have them check to see if there is a decimal point before adding:

```
-(IBAction)inTwo:(id)sender {
    if([resultField.text rangeOfString:@"."] == NSNotFound) {
        display = display*10+2;
        [resultfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",display]];
    }
    else {
        display += 2/10 * (resultField.length - [resultField.text rangeOfString:@"."] +1)
        [resultfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",display]];
    }
}
```

What you are doing here is first checking to see if there is a decimal point to see if you should be adding the digit to the ones place, or to the right of the decimal. If there is a decimal point, we add the digit divided by ten times the difference between the location of the decimal and the length of the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultfield.text = [result.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
```

You can't add a dot to `display` though, since it's not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You've only missed it by a little bit:

```
[resultfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.", display]];
```

If for some reason the parser is identifying the decimal point after the %f as some kind of specifier about the accuracy of the float or something (nearly positive it doesn't do this), just escape the decimal point:

```
[resultfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f\.", display]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly differently to the way you have chosen.  I'd have the buttons update the display directly and only convert to a number when needed for calculation.

e.g.

```
-(IBAction)inTwo:(id)sender 
{
    NSString* displayedText = [resultField text];
    [resultfield setText:[NSString stringByAppendingString: @"2"]];
}

-(IBAction)inDecimal:(id)sender 
{
    if (![self isDecimalAlreadyPressed]) // only allowed one decimal in the number
    {
        NSString* displayedText = [resultField text];
        [resultfield setText:[NSString stringByAppendingString: @"."]]; // actually want the localised character really
        [self setDecimalAlreadyPressed: YES];
    }
}
```

Then when you need to calculate something:

```
-(double) displayAsDouble
{
    NSDecimalNumber* displayAsDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [resultField text]];
    return [displayAsDecimal doubleValue];
}
```

By the way, consider leaving the number as an [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  There are methods on NSDecimalNumber to do simple arithmetic and they work in base 10, so you can use them and avoid a lot of the pesky representation issues with floating point numbers.